# Add an image to an API with Postman-Chrome

Tags: postman

I am working with a visual search service API. The engine should allow **upload** of images to the database and their identification when the same image is queried.

I am using the "PostMan" add-on to chrome for this purpose.

**Example:**

```
- The engine API Link:  {API_URL}
- to add a new image should add: /refimages/
```

Now in the documentation it says we should somehow provide these information:

```
{
  "refImgId":"img0093984",
 "score":3.48
}
```

as JSON file and the

```
Image URL
```

I am not sure I know how I can provide these information to in Postman. I cannot find where the image URL can be provided. Do you have any ideas? Thanks for suggestions.

The file should be of format: multipart/form-data

Answer (score 1):

If you look to the far right you can see "Text" change that to **File**, now you can choose a file to upload/post

[image]

Comment: Thanks I actually came across to this solution in the net. I tried it but the serve is giving me this error: `{
  "code": 404,
  "contactEmail": null,
  "description": "The server has not found anything matching the request URI",
  "homeRef": "/",
  "reasonPhrase": "Not Found",
  "uri": "http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html#sec10.4.5"
}`

Comment: Hm try to add a header:
**Accept: application/json**

Comment: And make sure that your body is set to form-data

Comment: The header is now: `Accept: application/json`. The body contains a `username` and `password` in json password format where I used it and obtained a token. The token allows me to use the API for 60 minutes. However, I Donot if I should some how use the API provided to me or not. Maybe this is the reason I cannot upload the image. I am receiving a similar error

Comment: do not know (my typo)

Comment: Ah okey, well I remember that I had the same problem using a API built with laravel. The API expected JSON data so after I added **Accept: application/json** it worked. Is it a public API ur using? If so give me a link so I can take a look